# Dealing with floating point errors during vector rotations

Tags: python, math, vector, floating-point

I am currently producing some code that deals with 3D vectors and calculating the angle between them after rotating them according to a set of euler angles. Part of this is normalising the vectors onto the 0,0,1 axis. This is mainly just so I can easily plot distribution plots and vector diagrams etc. To calculate the offset and the vector about which to rotate I am just using the dot and cross products as shown below:

```
def RotationMatrix(axis, rotang):
    """
    This uses Euler-Rodrigues formula.
    """
    #Input taken in degrees, here we change it to radians
    theta = rotang * 0.0174532925
    axis = np.asarray(axis)
    #Ensure axis is a unit vector
    axis = axis/math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    #calclating a, b, c and d according to euler-rodrigues forumla requirments
    a = math.cos(theta/2)
    b, c, d = axis*math.sin(theta/2)
    a2, b2, c2, d2 = a*a, b*b, c*c, d*d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b*c, a*d, a*c, a*b, b*d, c*d
    #Return the rotation matrix
    return np.array([[a2+b2-c2-d2, 2*(bc-ad), 2*(bd+ac)],
                     [2*(bc+ad), a2+c2-b2-d2, 2*(cd-ab)],
                     [2*(bd-ac), 2*(cd+ab), a2+d2-b2-c2]])


def ApplyRotationMatrix(vector, rotationmatrix):
    """
    This function take the output from the RotationMatrix function and
    uses that to apply the rotation to an input vector
    """
    a1 = (vector[0] * rotationmatrix[0, 0]) + (vector[1] * rotationmatrix[0, 1]) + (vector[2] * rotationmatrix[0, 2])
    b1 = (vector[0] * rotationmatrix[1, 0]) + (vector[1] * rotationmatrix[1, 1]) + (vector[2] * rotationmatrix[1, 2])
    c1 = (vector[0] * rotationmatrix[2, 0]) + (vector[1] * rotationmatrix[2, 1]) + (vector[2] * rotationmatrix[2, 2])

    return np.array((a1, b1, c1))


def CalculateAngleBetweenVector(vector, vector2):
    """
    Does what it says on the tin, outputs an angle in degrees between two input vectors.
    """
    dp = np.dot(vector, vector2)

    maga = math.sqrt((vector[0] ** 2) + (vector[1] ** 2) + (vector[2] ** 2))
    magb = math.sqrt((vector2[0] ** 2) + (vector2[1] ** 2) + (vector2[2] ** 2))
    magc = maga * magb

    dpmag = dp / magc

    #These if statements deal with rounding errors of floating point operations
    if dpmag > 1:
        error = dpmag - 1
        print('error = {}, do not worry if this number is very small'.format(error))
        dpmag = 1
    elif dpmag < -1:
        error = 1 + dpmag
        print('error = {}, do not worry if this number is very small'.format(error))
        dpmag = -1


    angleindeg = ((math.acos(dpmag)) * 180) / math.pi

    return angleindeg

axis = (0,0,1)
Vector1 = (0,1,0)
#ensure things are unit vectors
Vector1 = Vector1 / np.linalg.norm(Vector1)
#calculate the offset and axis of rotation to take vector to the z axis
angle1 = CalculateAngleBetweenVector(axis, Vector1)
cross1 = np.cross(axis, Vector1)
RM1 = RotationMatrix(cross1, angle1)
Vector1rot = ApplyRotationMatrix(Vector1, RM1)
print(Vector1rot)
```

Everything seems to work fine however if you just copy and paste the code above you will likely find that the rotated vector is 1x10^-9, 0, 1 rather than 0,0,1.

Is there an easy way round this floating point operation issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be used for rounding off float

```
print(np.around(Vector1rot,decimals=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need accuracy better than that? I think you want to first answer what floating point accuracy you need, and why. Specifically, to your question about reducing floating point errors, you could up the floating point quantization with numpy's long double.

Also, I should also point out that you could be better served using quaternions, depending on your application.

Comment: Not at all this was more of a nit picky it is untidy post as it should sit directly on the 0,0,1 axis. Also I am getting euler angles from another source so this ended up being the easiest way.

Comment: @j.t.2.4.6 Ah, if you just want the print to be clean you can do raghu's suggestion. Or if you want to get really fancy use a f-string literal string.  

print(f'The angle between the axis and the vector is: {np.around(Vector1rot,decimals=1)}')